# Flag did not change its color to red after the first try

Tags: bug, flags

I flagged a comment as 'No longer needed', but flag did not become red instantly.
I flagged the same comment again and now it's red.
So, I've used two tries on one comment.
The problem is that flag did not become red instantly. Question [Op type not registered 'cond_true_5' in binary running on DESKTOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70985234/op-type-not-registered-cond-true-5-in-binary-running-on-desktop)

In flag history it is also shown as flagged.
[image]

[image: 98 flags left today]

Comment: You didn't flag the same comment twice. The first comment you flagged was auto-deleted because it matched rules for that. You then flagged the second comment.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Maybe it was the same comment posted twice.

Comment: @vitaliis: There were 2 different comments by different users; the one you flagged (that comment was auto-deleted), and another one responding to that that you also flagged (and that comment was then deleted by a mod).